# I forgot to release hand brake and drove a little. Is my car damaged?

Tags: handbrake

I drive my car about 8 meters and forgot to release the hand brake.

My car is new and 2016 model what will be happen.  I am worried.

Answer (score 1):

Your car is fine.  You're shortened the life of the brake pads by the tiniest amount, that's all.  Don't make a habit of this though.